# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ diverges for infinitely many $z$ with $|z|=1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

**Problem:**

I need to show that the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ diverges for infinitely many $z$ with $|z|=1$. I tried to prove it by contradiction by assuming that diverges for finitely many $z$'s, but I wasn't successful. Anyone can prove it?

Comment: It diverges for __all__ $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert = 1$. The terms of the sum don't converge to $0$.

Comment: You must mean diverges to $\infty$, since it does not converge anywhere on the unit circle.

Comment: @AndréNicolas "You must mean diverges to $\infty$". Or: Does not converge to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to expand on @DanielFischer's comment because I think the following fact is often overlooked by students:

**Fact.** Let $\{\mathbf{x}_k\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\mathbf{x}_k=\mathbf0$ if and only if $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left|\mathbf{x}_k\right|=0$.

We can apply this fact to the question by using the so called **$n$th term test for divergence**. That is, let $z\in\mathbb C$ with $|z|=1$. Then 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|z^{n!}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z|^{n!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1^{n!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1=1\neq0
$$
Hence $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!}$ diverges for all $z\in\mathbb C$ with $|z|=1$.

Comment: Note that this argument works for any exponent, $z^{f(n)}$ instead of $z^{n!}$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $z=e^{2 \pi i q}$ for $q$ rational.